# Zipping folder with HTML files messes up webpage, any ideas?

Tags: html, css

I've made an HTML page which I have to send off which looks perfectly fine, I have zipped a folder with all my files in, but when I unzip it and open the page back up, some pictures are out of place and it looks like the page has zoomed out, any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not unzipping all the files in the zip and hence when you open the html file the css is not loading with it.

Unzip all the files to a folder - don't just open the zip file. Make sure they are all in the same directory structure as before (if any). Then open the html.

If that doesn't work, post the zip so we can see what gives.

Comment: When I zip it then unzip it https://i.gyazo.com/thumb/1200/78359f0bf4994db88207062e9ad44c35-jpg.jpg